# How do I stop a frame from appearing inside another frame?

Tags: html, iframe, frame

[image]

I am having an issue when when I open a link that appears inside a frame it opens it inside and I have a frame in a frame. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Please provide some more details. Does this happen on a foreign site, or is this a problem with a site that you are controlling?

Comment: **Provide minimal code**. Please first read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example